# Adding user input with state array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I have an existing array of data in a separate file that I am adding to with user input. The user input I am taking is 3 favorite movies. I am able to receive and push the rest of the data to an existing file. I am not sure if the state array is throwing me off but I am not able to add 3 strings into the array.

My state is as follows:

```
this.state = {
  isActive: false,
  id: 25,
  name: { first: "", last: "" },
  city: "",
  country: "",
  employer: "",
  title: "",
  favoriteMovies: ['', '', '']
};
```

I am setting the state for user input as follows:

```
 handleFavoriteMoviesChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ favoriteMovies: [...this.state.favoriteMovies, e.target.value]})
 };
```

These are my 3 input fields:

```
    <input
      placeholder="favorite movies"
      value={this.state.favoriteMovies[0]}
      onChange={this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange}
    />
    <input
      placeholder="favorite movies"
      value={this.state.favoriteMovies[1]}
      onChange={this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange}
    />
    <input
      placeholder="favorite movies"
      value={this.state.favoriteMovies[2]}
      onChange={this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the value of the `favoriteMovies` on its particular index then you can `setState` as below: [CODESANDBOX DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-blackburn-z7tyy?file=/src/App.js:616-1144)

```
  handleFavoriteMoviesChange = (e, index) => {
    this.setState({
      favoriteMovies: this.state.favoriteMovies.map((movie, i) => {
        if (i === index) return e.target.value;
        return movie;
      })
    });
  };
```

and call `handleFavoriteMoviesChange` as:

```
<input
  placeholder="favorite movies"
  value={this.state.favoriteMovies[0]}
  onChange={(e) => this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange(e, 0)}
/>
<input
  placeholder="favorite movies"
  value={this.state.favoriteMovies[1]}
  onChange={(e) => this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange(e, 1)}
/>
<input
  placeholder="favorite movies"
  value={this.state.favoriteMovies[2]}
  onChange={(e) => this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange(e, 2)}
/>
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. Just so I understand this, the handle function is setting the state for favoriteMovies and creating a new array with map. Checking if 'i' matches the index in the value input in the render, if it does return the input, if not return 'movie'?

Comment: That's correct. I'd like to add more. You just need two things to set the value `1) index` and `2) value`. We are externally passing both the values. You can get the `value` from `e.target.value` but you need to have `index` also. So Instead passing the function as `this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange`, I've passed a new function that internally call `this.handleFavoriteMoviesChange` with both values `value` and `index`.

Comment: You can also see [SANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-flower-w0bwh?file=/src/App.js) to simplify more if you use `map` on `input`, which will work if there are more than 3 `favoriteMovies`.